# Bat-file prohibit user input

Tags: powershell, input, batch-file

I'm making a .bat-file run a powershell script, and I need to make sure the script does not ask for user input og anything as such may halt the clean running of the script.
So my question's are:

1. How do I set input of all kind disabled?
2. Is there anything else I need to think about when running a powershell script remotely on a computer where the computers users shall have no interaction with the script what so ever?

Thanks
Have a good weekend! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-NonInteractive` switch on PowerShell.exe.  From the usage info:

```
-NonInteractive
    Does not present an interactive prompt to the user.
```

I've not used it myself so I can't say how well it works. YMMV. :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. You can disable input with the NonInteractive switch but commands that prompts the user will still wait for input.
2. There are many cmdlets that prompts for confirmation. You can try and set the $ConfirmPreference preference variable to 'none' to override prompting.

Other than that, the best thing would be to test your script before you use it in production. That's the best way to find out if your scripts can hang waiting for someone to respond.

Comment: Thanks Shay, i've not tested the $confirmpreference but as I read I understood that this is mighty usefull! thanks!